# Laravel Auth:attempt not working in test?

Tags: laravel

I've been trying to simply change a password, and then authenticate it, and Auth::attempt has been returning false:

```
    $email = "test6@mycompany.com";
    $pass  = md5("123");
    $credentials= [ 'email'    => $email,
                    'password' => $pass];

    $user = User::where("email" , $email)->first();
    $user->password = $pass;
    $user->save();


    dd(Auth::attempt($credentials));
```

I also have this part in the user model...

```
 public function setPasswordAttribute($pass){

    $this->attributes['password'] = Hash::make($pass);

}
```

Does anyone have any ideas what could I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This always happen, just as I post the question, I have an epiphany...

my password field was too short to contain the password so it always saved only part of the hashed string.